# Does media wiki support links inside highlighted code?

Tags: mediawiki

Assume I have the following code section:

```
<syntaxhighlight lang = "php">
function my_func($str) {
  $arr = split($str, ' ');
}
</syntaxhighlight>
```

This would be highlighted with the help of [Geshi extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi). However, I would also like to make **split** as a url link to the external site with documentation explaining what this function does. Is there like any way to do that in MediaWiki for the highlighted code?

Answer (score 0):

Since Geshi works like the `<pre>` tag to display the code is displayed as typed instead of parsing it as wikicode, mediawiki can't parse anything inside it. Therefore its impossible to add a 'normal' link using wiki code.

Good news is that GeSHi already have exactly what you need!

First, you will need to set in localSettings.php:

`$wgSyntaxHighlightKeywordLinks = true;`

By doing that it will each function will be a link to `http://www.php.net/<function name>` (since your example is using php code).

If what you want is a link to somewhere else (your own site maybe), you will need to edit the 'URLS' array in `$IP/SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi/geshi/geshi/php.php` 
(more information on [GeSHi's documentation](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/geshi-doc.html#language-file-urls))

And if you will need links on functions for other languages other than php, just edit the according file instead. For example:

`$IP/SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi/geshi/geshi/lolcode.php`